# Scripting with 'for' and grep/egrep

Tags: command-line, awk, for, ash

I'm trying to learn some more Linux, and from experience the best way is to try to bang your head against the wall. So now that I've done a task manually a few times I would like to automate it. This involves making a oneliner to kill some tasks so I can restart them.

At the moment I'm working with the following:

```
for i in `ps aux | egrep "[c]ouchpotato|[s]abnzbd|[s]ickbeard|[d]eluge|[n]zbhydra"|awk '{print $2, $11, $12}'`; do echo $i; done
```

The thing is that as soon as I run the for loop it breaks up the lines I get from awk.

Running 
`ps aux | egrep "[c]ouchpotato|[s]abnzbd|[s]ickbeard|[d]eluge|[n]zbhydra"|awk '{print $2, $11, $12}'`
gives me the result I'm looking for, namely:

```
27491 /usr/local/couchpotatoserver-custom/env/bin/python /usr/local/couchpotatoserver-custom/var/CouchPotatoServer/CouchPotato.py
27504 /usr/local/deluge/env/bin/python /usr/local/deluge/env/bin/deluged
27525 /usr/local/deluge/env/bin/python /usr/local/deluge/env/bin/deluge-web
27637 /usr/local/nzbhydra/env/bin/python /usr/local/nzbhydra/share/nzbhydra/nzbhydra.py
27671 /usr/local/sabnzbd/env/bin/python /usr/local/sabnzbd/share/SABnzbd    /SABnzbd.py
28084 /usr/local/sickbeard-custom/env/bin/python /usr/local/sickbeard-custom/var/SickBeard/SickBeard.py
```

But adding it to my for loop breaks it into:

```
27491
/usr/local/couchpotatoserver-custom/env/bin/python
/usr/local/couchpotatoserver-custom/var/CouchPotatoServer/CouchPotato.py
27504
/usr/local/deluge/env/bin/python
/usr/local/deluge/env/bin/deluged
etc...
```

My goal is for $i to contain the whole line - is this possible? Also, is it possible to use get only the command from $11 and $12? I don't need to have the whole path to python and I don't even need to have the whole path to the application.

Thanks!

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/65304) - in particular the section *Why do I need to write "$foo"? What happens without the quotes?*

Comment: @steeldriver: I'm not entirely sure what you wanted me to do here. I changed to bash, as I read from the article that it would accept spaces in a variable, I changed the backticks to $(...), but then all of a sudden there was just one long line. The for-loop would just hit everything in one go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the `for` loop output is broken apart at the word boundaries, viz., whitespaces/newlines. Whereas what you said you wanted is the whole line to come contained in the `$i`.

So you need to do these 2 things:

1. set the input field separator to a newline.
2. disable the wildcards expansion.

   ```
   set -f;IFS=$'\n'; for i in `.....`;do echo "$i"; done
   ```

Note: DO NOT quote the backquotes else you shall end up giving to the `for` loop one big blob of argument,which would be the whole ps's output, and that doesn't do you no good.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the main part of my problem :)

P.S. I wasn't allowed to upvote your answer as I'm too new...